# sequalize - find user in array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have `user: { name: 'Patrick', ... }`

I have an array like: `['Patrick, 'James']`

I want to find all users depending on my array. I ended up with something like this:

```
models.User.findAll({
        where: { name: {
            $in: names
          }
        }
      })
```

but it throws error. Also I tried this:

```
models.User.findAll({
    where: { name: {
        $like: { $any: names }
      }
    }
  })
```

But it also fails.
How to find all this users, when I have an array with names?

Comment: What is the error output ?

Comment: first situation: `SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]` or second: `TypeError: val.replace is not a function`